# Using or Converting Mex driver in C Program

Tags: c, linux, matlab, shared-libraries, mex

I have a device driver that is distributed as Matlab mex file. I want to use the device with ROS on Linux, without Matlab. Is it somehow be possible to use a Matlab Mex file in a C/C++ program?

I can think of three ways:

- Just treat it as dynamic library and try to link against it directly. The C program would need to use the [`mexFunction()` entry point](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mexfunction.html) inside
- Use [Matlab Compiler](https://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler_sdk/ml_code/compile-a-standalone-application-with-the-standalone-compiler-app_bt2fm30-1.html) to convert it to an actual shared C/C++ library
- Use [Matlab Engine](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/calling-matlab-engine-from-c-c-and-fortran-programs.html) and call a Matlab script that uses the mex.

I don't like the third option, because the program should run on an ARM-based embedded PC without Matlab (Not sure if the [Matlab Runtime](https://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/mcr.html) runs on ARM).

The Mex code doesn't use any Toolbox functions, only some standard Matlab Mex functions like `mexErrMsgTxt()` or `mxCreateString()` and FTDI's D2XX library.

Has anybody done something like this? Can this work?

Comment: I tested Matlab's Library Compiler App. It works great and I was able to write a C program that uses it. It is a little complicated to use because all the arguments are [mwArray](https://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler_sdk/cxx/mwarray.html)s. The big problem is however, that you need the Matlab Compiler Runtime, which does not exist for my armv7l target. :(

Comment: MATLAB mex C files are just C files with MATLAB objects. Can't you modify the files and make it a full C code?

Comment: That's what I ended up doing now. I was hoping to avoid that, because the source code is from another company and is normally not distributed.